# Why stripe subscription billing cycle not charging on same days for all the customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created subscription stripe for many customers, I have its start date is `1st August`, So it has started subscription on 1st august, after then it should have to be charge on `1st september`, but still it doesn't charge, why it doesn't charge ?

Comment: Can you check next billing date for your subscriptions?

Comment: Do you have any trial periods added to the subscription?